# How to put consecutive citations with a comma instead of a hyphen?

Tags: citing, multiple-citations, cite-package

I have a bunch of citations in my report for which I am using `\cite{author1, author2, author3, author4, author5}`. The output of this is `[1-5]`. But I want something explicit like `[1,2,3,4,5]`. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just load the `cite` package with the option `nocompress`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@misc{a, author="Anne Author",    title="Thoughts", year=3001}
@misc{b, author="Brenda Brown",   title="Thoughts", year=3002}
@misc{c, author="Carla Case",     title="Thoughts", year=3003}
@misc{d, author="Daniela Dixit",  title="Thoughts", year=3004}
@misc{e, author="Erica Easterlin",title="Thoughts", year=3005}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[nocompress]{cite}
\bibliographystyle{plain} % or some other suitable bib style

\begin{document}
\cite{a,b,c,d,e}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```